# "import py" > No module named py

Tags: python-2.7, import

I am trying to run a py.test script. When the script try to import py, I get a "No module named py"

I have py.test and python successfully installed.

My error message:

```
$ python
>>> import py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named py
```

The sqript I am trying to run, are named run_tests.py, and are made by my University. It runs for all other people. It starts like this:

```
# This script can be used to automatically check the assignments of students
import py
import os
import sys
import argparse
verbose = True

# List of assignment names and achie.....
```

My py.test version: 2.7.2, python version: 2.7.9, runing OSX

Comment: There is no module named `py`. Do you mean that you wrote a script and saved it as `py.test`? Why would you do that and why would you expect Python to look for a file named `py.test` when you write `import py`?

Comment: @JohnColeman: there is library named `py`: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py/1.4.30

Comment: @TommasoDiBucchianico good to know -- I should have said that there is no standard module which is part of the default Python install.

Answer (score 3):

Install the `py` library on your system:

```
pip install py
```

Comment: Hi, just did this, still have the same problem. $ pip install py
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): py in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
$ python
>>> import py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named py

Comment: Are you sure, you are using python 2.7? What does `python --version` say? anyway try also `pip install py --upgrade`

Comment: `$ python --version` say
`Python 2.7.9`, `pip install py --upgrade` did not help. Still get the same message

Answer (score 0):

I did figure it out myself.

I had an alias in my bash profile:

```
alias python="python2.7"
```

That messed up. I removed it and everything works. *facepalm*