# No module named py in django 1.4

Tags: django, python-2.7

Trying to execute `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`:

```
[31/Mar/2019 08:19:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/root/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/root/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/root/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 177, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/root/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 222, in handle_uncaught_exception
    if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
  File "/root/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/root/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named py
```

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Python: 2.7

Django: 1.4

Installing it with `pip install py` didn't help.

Also I have no alias in my bashrc as suggested here:["import py" > No module named py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32695411/import-py-no-module-named-py)

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: which module do you want to install?

Comment: none. I'm trying to run the server and visit my project from the browser

Comment: find somewhere you try to import `py`

Comment: Show your wsgi file. But note Django 1.4 is several years old, unsupported, and totally insecure.

Comment: Please show your `ROOT_URLCONF` setting as well.

Comment: @Alasdair thank you that request allowed me to understand where the problem was. previously I was looking at imports and not string values and that's why I didn't spot it. Temporary added an answer, but feel free to add yours and I'll accept your answer instead.

Comment: Glad you fixed the problem. Your answer is fine, go ahead and accept it when the website lets you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Alasdair answer I checked the configuration and `ROOT_URLCONF` was indeed responsible for the error. It pointed at `mymodule.urls.py` while the correct value is `mymodule.urls`

Changing this made the error go away.